# upgrading to iCloud drive

Tags: ios8, ios-simulator, icloud-drive

My application is using iCloud. In the xcode 6 GM edition, I am getting the error which signifies that `URLForUbiquityContainer` is nil. So, I decided to turn on iCloud drive in my simulator (which uses my apple ID). However, it says that once I upgrade to iCloud Drive (in simulator), my real devices will not be able to access the documents currently stored in iCloud until they are also upgraded to iOS 8. So, is that just a test warning or can it really impact my devices ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you upgrade your iCloud account from Ubiquity to iCloud Drive, there is no going back.  This is the case whether you initiate the upgrade from OS X Yosemite, an iOS 8 device, or an iOS 8 simulator.

If you want to stay on Ubiquity for the benefit of older OS versions but test functionality, I suggest you setup a development account for that.